# Mouse Handling on Image Control of WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv

I am quite noob in `WPF`. I am creating a `WPF` application and using a `EmguCV` library for `image Processing`. I found that I can't use `ImageBox` in `WPF`. So I am using `NamedWindow` to show `image` then I decided to use `Image Control`to show the image on the `window`. I am trying to draw the `rectangle` over that `image` but rectangle in not drawn at other place. So can anyone tell me what is wrong in the code.

Basically I want to take ROI of that image.

**EDIT:-**
I put the `Canvas` inside `grid` a put the `Image Control` inside that `Canvas`

**My XAML Code **

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,2,-1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="138*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="139*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Convert" Margin="139.053,432.066,0,0" Click="button_Click" Height="27.934" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="113.947" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Load Palette" Margin="308,432.066,0,0" Click="button1_Click_1" Height="27.934" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Load Gray Image" Margin="48,432.066,0,0" Click="button2_Click" Height="27.934" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="104"/>

    <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Margin="81,86.5,27.245,120.5" Grid.Column="1">
        <Image x:Name="image3" Height="263" Width="238"/>
    </Canvas>
    <Image x:Name="image1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="263" Margin="10,86.5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255.5"/>
    <Image x:Name="image2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="393" Margin="308,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

**And My C# code is**

```
        private Boolean isdragging = false;
        private System.Windows.Point startPoint;
        private System.Windows.Point endPoint;
        private System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle rect;  
   private void image3_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        startPoint = e.GetPosition(MyCanvas);
        isdragging = true;
        if(rect != null)
            MyCanvas.Children.Remove(rect);
        rect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle
        {
            Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue,
            StrokeThickness = 2
        };
        System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetLeft(rect, startPoint.X);
        System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetTop(rect, startPoint.Y);
        MyCanvas.Children.Add(rect);
    }

    private void image3_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        rect = null;
        isdragging = false;
        endPoint = e.GetPosition(MyCanvas);
    }
    private void image3_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isdragging == true)
        {
            var pos = e.GetPosition(MyCanvas);
            var x = Math.Min(pos.X, startPoint.X);
            var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, startPoint.Y);
            var w = Math.Max(pos.X, startPoint.X) - x;
            var h = Math.Max(pos.Y, startPoint.Y) - y;
            rect.Width = w;
            rect.Height = h;
            System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);
            System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetTop(rect, y);
        }
    }
```

I am using `Event Handler` over the `Canvas` but it doesn't showing the `rectangle`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Make your self familiar with [WPF layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview). Do not use Margins to position elements. Instead, put them in a Canvas, and set their Width and Height and their Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties.

Comment: I have try this I am editing the question.

Comment: I know there are some mistake I have done in this code, basically it doesn't showing any rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Clemens, I have got the answer, Actually I haven't add the event handler to `image3 Image Control` that's why it is not showing the output.

```
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Margin="81,86.5,27.245,120.5" Grid.Column="1">
    <Image x:Name="image3" Height="263" Width="238" MouseLeftButtonDown="image3_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="image3_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="image3_MouseMove"/>
</Canvas>
```